# How to trigger Chokidar event programmaticaly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine

I have a class, which is using Chokidar and now need to test it with jasmine. This is method, where chokidar comes on board:

```
public watch(path: string) {
    var watchOptions: chokidar.WatchOptions = <chokidar.WatchOptions> {
        persistent: true
    };
    this.watcher = chokidar.watch(path, watchOptions);
    this.watcher.on("add", (fileName: string, stats: fs.Stats) => {
        this.sendNotifyAction(new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Add, fileName));
    }).on("change", (fileName: string, stats: fs.Stats) => {
        this.sendNotifyAction(new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Change, fileName));
    })
}
```

I want to have in my test something like:

```
    it("Should send notification, when internal directory is added", () => {
        runs(() => {
            flag = false;
            pathWatch.watch(dirPath);

            //TRIGGER chokidar on.add event??
            //spyOn(pathWatch.watcher, "on").and.callFake((params) => {
            //    flag = true;
            //});

        });
        waitsFor((): boolean => {
            return flag;
        }, "failure", 5000);

        runs(() => {
            var expectedNotifyAction = new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Add, notificationInternalDirPath);
            expect(subscriber.processNotifyAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedNotifyAction);
        });
    });
```

The problem is that I don't know how to emulate Chokidar events. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: why not just write to a file and add a file with node.js file API, it should trigger chokidar

Comment: that's how I do it now, but it's a bit messy and I'm interesting in how to emulate chokidar events

Comment: from chokidar tests https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/master/test.js#L162

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watcher instance inherits from [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), so you can call `.emit()` on it (although I'm not sure how/if that would work with TypeScript):

```
pathWatch.watcher.emit('add', PATH, STATS);
```